# GoogleAPIClient connection failed

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to connect to GoogleDrive through my application. The Drive gets connected through certain gmail_id's but connection fails for few ids.

Can any guide me what change i need to do? Why the connection vary from id to id?

**Code:**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAccountName == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            //                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
            //                    .setAccountName(mAccountName)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
//          .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        super.connectionFailed(result);
        ++count;
        if(!result.hasResolution()){
            System.out.println("result code = " + result.toString());
            if(dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            String message = "";
            if(!SUICommon.isInternetOn(BackupDbData.this)){
                message = "Check your internet connection and try again.";
            }
            else{
                message = "Unable to connect to drive.";
            }
            SingleButtonDialog singleButtonDialog = new SingleButtonDialog(BackupDbData.this, message,true);
            singleButtonDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.rounded_button);
            singleButtonDialog.setCancelable(false);
            singleButtonDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AnandSavjani Please check the code above

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/connecting-to-google-drive-from-an-android-app

Comment: Page not found error

Comment: now check i correct that link @Megha

Comment: According to me, logic is same, execution is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81062/discussion-between-anand-savjani-and-megha).

Comment: 1. How did you switch to use the second account name? Did you actually call GoogleApiClient.Builder#setAccountName? (It's commented in your code)
2. Result code 4 is SIGN_IN_REQUIRED (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) and it should come with a resolution. The code you posted doesn't seem to do anything with the resolution.

Comment: I'm not sure what role the "gmail_id" is playing here, do you mean the Google Account, like user@gmail.com?